# Query returned values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write an SQL query which uses results from previous one.

For example - I have a table Orders with fields: order_id, date and value. I need to get all dates from column date where value is larger than 5:

```
SELECT date 
FROM Orders 
WHERE value > 5;
```

Then I need to return all values for dates, which are +2 days from the returned ones. Is it possible to write short query without using LOOP statement?

Here is an example table:

[image]

I am expecting to get the result:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Also, which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

his will give you what you need.

```
select date, value  
from Orders where date in
(
  SELECT date + INTERVAL 5 DAY as date
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE value > 100;
)
```